# Change height of an element automatically when window width is changed

Tags: jquery, css, height, responsive

I have some inputs which shape is square (same height same width). Their widths are related to the windows width in a responsively. But I want them to change the height automatically too when window's WIDTH is changed so they preserve the square shape.

Does this behaviour exist on CSS or jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css)

Comment: try to use vh for height and vw for width, otherwise use % for width and height in css

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with jquery resize(). You would have to get the width of the window whenver it is resize and set up your squares width and height accordingly.

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
```

I created a simple fiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/mdoLaxtL/7/ . Hope that helps.